# split String not working in java can't import `split`

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to split a string as the code below

```
String []data = {"3.5,2.3,4.2,5.4,7.4,2.7"};
String s[] = data.split("\\,");

double point3[] = new Double [s.length];
double allPoint[] = new double [s.length];

for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
   point3[2] = Double.parseDouble(s[2]);
   //lng[i] = Double.parseDouble(s[i]);
   allPoint[i] = Double.parseDouble(s[i]);
}
```

I also tried with `data.split(",");` **But** the problem is not with backslashes, it gives error at `split` and hint shows that

> cannot find symbol,   symbol:   method split(String)

I'm unable to import `split` 
what can I do now.

Comment: You need a string to use `split()`  not an array.

Comment: `data[0].split(",");` may also work in case of array.

Answer (score 6):

The method [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) belongs to [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), not to [`Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html). To make this work, you must define your data as `String data = "3.5,2.3,4.2,5.4,7.4,2.7";` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here `data` represent a string array. And data present in `0` position. For getting data from data array used `data[0]`.

This code should work for you :

```
String []data = {"3.5,2.3,4.2,5.4,7.4,2.7"};

String s[] = data[0].split("\\,");

double allPoint[] = new double [s.length];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
      System.out.println(s[i]);
}

Output : 
  3.5
  2.3
  4.2
  5.4
  7.4
  2.7
```

Comment: yes its working But why index 0 is necessary to split

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is correct **But** it can also be done with array as `data[0].split(",");`.

Because in case of array data is at 0th index and we can split it with its index value.

And if you use this:

> double point3[] = new Double [s.length];

it means you are making object of `double` because `Double` with capital `D` indicate to object. your `allpoint[]` array may work correctly.